# Nexus Sonatype configuration

Tags: maven, nexus, sonatype

Context :
I have a Nexus Sonatype Server installed on a machine A, and I have installed a new Nexus Sonatype Server on another machine B. I want to configure maven setting.xml to point to the first Nexus of the machine A, and configure this Nexus of A to point to the Nexus of B.
Problem :
I don't know how to solve this, I have searched on google before I come here friends.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Server migration to new version? Why not installing the new Nexus version on the Server A ?

Comment: Thank you #khmarbaise for your response. This is a kind of constraint, what I can do is what I have written above, I can't change anything of what is done or installed! You see?

Comment: Are you doing a migration or not? If so that's the wrong way... You need to configure the Nexus on Machine a in your settings.xml and in Nexus A you can define a repository to point to Nexus B...Read the docs of Nexus and google for settings.xml configuration for Maven.

Comment: Thank you very much khmarbaise. Yes this is a migration of an existing project that was using the Nexus of A, and now we want to use another Nexus of B, (in addition of Nexus A). I have configured maven setting to point to Nexus A, and in Nexus A I have added a proxy repository that point to Nexus B, but dependencies putted in Nexus B don't be matched by Nexus A!! I hope you could help me in that problem.

Comment: Sorry, I want to say : configure maven setting to point to the new Nexus of B, and in Nexus B I have added a proxy repository that point to the old one Nexus A, the problem is Nexus B doesn't find dependencies managed by Nexus A!

Comment: The order of definition is important in Nexus. Take a look there.